# C++: How does a for loop like this one work (using pointers)?

Tags: c++, pointers, for-loop

I just came across this for loop in a reference book but I'm not really sure what's going on in the comparison since it's just a lone pointer.

```
char input[300], *p, *q[300], **r = q;
cin.getline(input, 300);
for (p = input; *p; p++)
```

How would it work?

Comment: That would be the same as `*p != 0`.

Comment: Bang - head hitting table - Where is the comparison?

Answer (score 5):

`input` is a null-terminated string. `cin.getline` will place a `0` after the last character of the read string or at `input[299]` if the line exceeds 299 characters.

The char value gets implicitely converted to a boolean. It becomes true if it's not zero and consequently false if it's zero. Thus the loop condition is equivalent to `*p != 0`.

Therefor the loop will iterate over the array until it comes across a zero, the end of the string.

Comment: it will actually place ASCII '\0' after it, i'm not sure zero is the same.

Comment: @self the null character is actually a zero. Semantic reasons aside, this also allows faster iteration as comparison against zero is usually faster than comparing two arbitrary numbers.

Answer (score 4):

The second expression in a for statement is evaluated for "truthiness". A character is true if is not equal to 0. The for loop could be changed to the following equivalent one:

```
for (p = input; *p != 0; p++)
```

Since strings are null-terminated, this is how one iterates through the characters in a string, and stop at the end.